# How to solve this complex differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

1) What type of differential equation is:
$$ \frac{\partial A(t)}{\partial t}=a*k(t)^{2}*A(t)+i*b*k(t)*A(t) $$

2) Can I solve it by separation of variables? If not, how to do so?

3) Does it change anything in that the second part on the RHS is imaginary or schould I just treat it like a normal constant?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation can be written as
$$
\frac{dA}{dt} = [ak^2(t) + ibk(t)] A.
$$
You can see that it can indeed be solved by separation of variables as long as you known $k(t)$ (otherwise, you can write the solution for $A$ in terms of $k$).

After you solve it, you will get $A$ as the exponential of some integrals. If your function $k(t)$ is real valued, your solution will have a real part and a imaginary part, that you will be able to obtain using the [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). Before that, you can deal with $i$ as a mere constant.